# How to play a repeating audio when a person is near the proximity sensor and stop when he moves away

Tags: android, audio, proximitysensor

I want to play a repeating audio when my hand is near the proximity sensor and stop the audio once the hand is moved away from the sensor. This is the code i have written.. The audio plays when i go near the proximity sensor but it does not stop when my hand moves away. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor proxy;
TextView tv;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    proxy = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    //tv.setText("Maximum range = " + proxy.getMaximumRange() + proxy.getName());

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,proxy,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alarm);
        if(event.values[0] < proxy.getMaximumRange()){
            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
        else{
            mp.stop();
        }
        //tv.setText("SEnsor NOT activated");
        }
    }


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime in the when the onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) is called your code is initializing the media player. 
When you are trying to call stop() method, it is being called in the new object you just created and the previous object is somewhere running the alarm in memory already, hence it is not stopping. 
According to documentation stop() has no effect if you start() is never called yet, ideally, it should throw an exception but apparently, there is no effect.
I have modified your code, which I suggest, should work (possibly).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor proxy;
TextView tv;
static final MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alarm);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    proxy = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    /**
     * set on prepared listener
     */


 mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                   mp.start();
                   mp.setLooping(true);

                }
            });





}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,proxy,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY){
       if(event.values[0] < proxy.getMaximumRange()){
            mp.prepareAsync();
        }
        else{
            mp.stop();
        }

    }
}


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

}

Comment: The code is not working. The audio does not play at all when it is created in the oncreate function.

Comment: Is there any error? or it just doesn't work? you can try replacing mp= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alarm); with mp= MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(),R.raw.alarm);

Answer (score 0):

I use exoplayer to play audio file.

You must add this library:

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.4'
```

and add read permission:

```
"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor sensor;
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ = 1 ;

private   SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestPermissions() ;

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

   initExoPlayer();


}

public void  initExoPlayer(){
    DefaultRenderersFactory defaultRenderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this , null , DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF);
    DefaultTrackSelector defaultTrackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(defaultRenderersFactory , defaultTrackSelector) ;
    String  agent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayer") ;
    ExtractorMediaSource extractorMediaSource  = new ExtractorMediaSource(your_audio_uri , new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this , agent)
            , new DefaultExtractorsFactory() , null , null) ;

    exoPlayer.prepare(extractorMediaSource);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    initExoPlayer();

            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'switch' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
        if (event.values[0] < sensor.getMaximumRange()) {
            exoPlayer.setAudioStreamType(C.STREAM_TYPE_VOICE_CALL);
            exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        } else {
            exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);

        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}




@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
public  void requestPermissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ);

    }

}
}
```